# How to rename a column of a bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to rename a column of a **bootstrap table?**  I want to rename the column name when pressing a button. if anyone knows please help me :)

Comment: give id to table header or the column header you to rename and on button click change the content.

Comment: Rahul, I did, but it didn't work :/ i am using a bootstrap table.

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: give id to <th id="id1"> and change the content on button click $("#btnid").on("click",function(){ $("#id1").text("Here goes your content") });

Comment: This is the HTML code with bootstrap

<table class="table-condensed" id="itemstock"  data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true">
    <thead>
      <th data-field="ItemCode" id="stockheaderdata">Item Code</th>
      <th data-field="ItemName">Itm Name</th>                     
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

i tried your code , but it is not working with bootstrap :/

Comment: Can u see the answer of Rino Raj? It worked. But i want to rename a specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. You can add codes which you have tried, to improve the question.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[type="button"]').click(function(){
        $('.table tr th').text('changed')
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Change">
```

Comment: Thank you Rino it worked, that's what i wanted :) n how i change a specific column? Assume, i want to rename 3rd column.

Comment: @MaheshGunasekara  `$('.table tr:eq(3)').find('td').text('changed')`

Comment: @MaheshGunasekara Please dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you. It may help others also

Comment: Thanks Rinoo :) it worked, in my bootstrap table i wanted to change the name of 7th column. this code worked                                      $('#itemstock tr:eq(0)').find('th:eq(7)').html('Stock In Transit');

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special needed for that, just change the column name using jquery's `.text()` inside buttons `click` handler.

**JS CODE:**

```
$(this).text('NewCol');
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dqq5B/247/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```html
<div>
    <table id="users" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr><th>#</th><th>name</th><th>age</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="1">Mike</a></td>
            <td>21</td>       
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="2">John</a></td>
            <td>28</td>       
        </tr>        
        
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="3">Mary</a></td>
            <td>24</td>       
        </tr>        
        
    </table>    
</div>
```